# Program hang with asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-asyncio

Here is my code:

```
import asyncio, socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('', 1234))
sock.setblocking(False)

queue = asyncio.Queue()

def sock_reader():
    print(sock.recv(1024))
    # x = yield from queue

def test_sock_reader():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.sendto(b'HELLO', ('127.0.0.1', 1234))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.add_reader(sock, sock_reader)
loop.call_later(0.5, test_sock_reader)
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

This is the output:

```
b'HELLO'
```

> When the line `# x = yield from queue` is uncommented the program is not printing `b'Hello'` anymore.

Why is the `yield from` affecting a command that should already be **executed**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is a combination of syntax and API definition.

First of, refer to the [documentation of `add_reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.add_reader), which states that it expects a *callback*. It is not obvious from the word itself, but by saying *callback* it means a regular function.

Now, when you uncomment the `# x = yield from queue` line, your `sock_reader` function actually becomes a generator/coroutine due to `yield from`, in which case when called like a regular function (i.e. `sock_reader(...)`), it returns a generator object, and does not get executed.

Comment: i want `sock_reader` to wait until the queue has an item. how to do it?

Comment: @DombiSzabolcs Have a look at the [UDP examples from the asyncio documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#udp-echo-server-protocol), and the [loop.create_datagram_endpoint method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.create_datagram_endpoint)